# Definition of externally declared variable works in one function, but not another

Tags: c++, winapi, linker

I'm writing a small, dialog based Win32 application. I need to create and show a second dialog when a menu button is clicked. I have the HWND declared in an external header file - wedge.h

**wedge.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <Windows.h>
#include "utilities.h"

extern HWND wedgedialog;
INT_PTR CALLBACK WedgeProc(HWND hDlg, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
```

When I try and define wedgedialog in my WinMain function and use the variable in my DialogProc function, I get an "unresolved external symbol" error from the linker. When I both define and use wedgedialog in my DialogProc, everything works fine. Why does the definition work in one function, but not the other? Keep in mind, my WinMain and DialogProc function are in the same file.

**main.cpp**

```
INT_PTR CALLBACK DialogProc(HWND hDlg, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
int WINAPI _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE h0, LPTSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
HWND hDlg;
MSG msg;
BOOL ret;
InitCommonControls();
hDlg = CreateDialogParam(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(MAIN), 0, DialogProc, 0);


HWND wedgedialog = CreateDialog(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(WEDGE), hDlg, WedgeProc);


ShowWindow(hDlg, nCmdShow);
HMENU menu = LoadMenu(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_MENU1));
SetMenu(hDlg, menu);
while ((ret = GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0)) != 0) {
    if (ret == -1)
        return -1;
    if (!IsDialogMessage(hDlg, &msg)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

}
return 0;
}

INT_PTR CALLBACK DialogProc(HWND hDlg, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
switch (uMsg)
{

case WM_CLOSE:
    DestroyWindow(hDlg);
    return TRUE;
    break;
case WM_DESTROY:
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    return TRUE;
    break;
case WM_COMMAND:
    switch (LOWORD(wParam))
    {
    case ID_EDIT_WEDGESETTINGS:

        ShowWindow(wedgedialog, SW_SHOW);
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
    break;
}
return FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not really defining a global variable.  You're declaring a local variable named wedgedialog of type HWND in the _tWinMain function.  That local variable doesn't get automatically promoted to a global just because you have an extern declaration.  The extern declaration does tell the compiler that there's a global variable somewhere, which is why the code in DialogProc compiles, but there's really no global to link to.

To make this work, you need to actually declare a global variable, outside of any function, like so:

```
HWND wedgedialog = NULL;
```

Then in the main function, remove the HWND specifier at the start of the line with the CreateDialog call, so that you're simply assigning to the global, not declaring a local.

You can leave the extern declaration in the header if you want, but you don't really need it unless you're using that global in some other function.  Although there are arguably better designs than using a global.  You could declare a class with a static member, to at least avoid the global namespace.  Or you could have a class with a static function to return a singleton object.

Answer (score 0):

"extern HWND wedgedialog;" doesn't actually allocate the variable. It just tells the compiler that the variable will be allocated in another file, and will be resolved during linking. In one of your other files there needs to be:

"HWND wedgedialog;"

To actually allocate the variable in memory.